# How I can get instance using "this", after I invoke method in other class

Tags: typescript

I have class Worker with method DoWork();

```
class Worker {
    DoWork() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

And I have other class

```
class Main {
    method: () => {};
    Invoker() {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        this.method = worker.DoWork();
        this.method();
    {
}
```

After running of Invoker I can see instance of Main in console.
How I can get instance of Worker?

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure you're using a typescript syntax here, and I did not understand exactly what you are looking for. Once you instanciate a class you've access to its instance using `this` keyword…

Comment: maybe you just want to just execute `worker.DoWork()`?